# ASP.Net IEnumerable List: store values to chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, linq, charts, ienumerable

I have an array of my x values for my chart and a Linq to Entity LIST that contains my y values.  How do I access my list to add their values to the chart.  this is what I have so far:

```
                //Get restaurant name & count of votes for each restaurant
                BL.BLaddVote obj1 = new BLaddVote();
                var votesList = obj1.countVotes();

                //Set chart x & y values:  here is where I'm stuck
                chtVotes.Series[0].Points.Add(<X VALUES>, <Y VALUES>);
```

How do I get the values from my anonlymous list into my chart?  Thanks in advance.

Additionally, here is the query to pull the data:

```
    public class NumVotesInfo
    {
        public string RestName { get; set; }
        public int NumVotes { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<NumVotesInfo> countVotes()
    {
        //Return the count of the number of reviews for a specific restaurant ID
        var NumVotes = from VOTE in db.VOTEs
                         group VOTE by VOTE.VOTE_VALUE into t
                         select new NumVotesInfo { RestName = t.Key, NumVotes = t.Count() };

        return NumVotes.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: What is the type that `countVotes` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to merge the list of X values and the list of Y values:

```
var pointList = myXValues.Zip(votesList, (a,b) => new { X = a, Y = b.NumVotes });
```

Now you have `X` and `Y` properties in your `pointList` and can use it for charting:

```
foreach(var point in pointList)
    chtVotes.Series[0].Points.Add(point.X, point.Y);
```

Alternatively, assuming still that both lists have the same length you can just use the index. This would require `countVotes()` to return a list not an `IEnumerable`, you can create the list by using `ToList()`:

```
var votesList = obj1.countVotes().ToList();
```

Now you can just use the index:

```
for(int i = 0; i< votesList.Count, i++)
{
      chtVotes.Series[0].Points.Add(myXValues[i], votesList[i].NumVotes);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, I have one IEnumerable list that is returning a listing of value pairs for RestName and RestVotes.  I want to plot those 2 values on the chart.  Something like:   chVotes.Series[0].Points.Add(votesList.RestName[i], votesList.RestVotes[i]);

Comment: I just added my data query to the question.

Comment: @Susan: Updated to take your data structure into account. As a side note you can declare your `countVotes()` method to return `IList<NumVotesInfo>` then you don't need to use `ToList()` again to use the index.

Comment: when I try to use votesList[i}, intellsense states that, "Cannot apply indesing to with [] to an expression type systems.Collection.Generic.IEnuerable<DL.DLAddVote.NumVotesInfo>

Comment: @Susan: That's because your method currently returns `IEnumerable<NumVotesInfo>` - see my previous comment or use `ToList()`